# Expand down automaticlly radcombobox in IE

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, radcombobox

I use radcombobox in my site and in fire fox works well but in IE when page has loaded all my radcombobox automatically expand.
Did anyone have this problem?
thank u for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can drop up combo box by java script when load page.